# Find if vector contains pair with second element equal to X

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, search, coding-efficiency

I have this vector:

```
using namespace std;

vector< pair<short, string> > vec = {};
```

And I want to find out if exists a pair `<a, b>` with `b == X`.

I know about `std::find` from `<algorithm>` but don't know how to apply it here.

Should I write my own function to do that?

```
bool is_in_vec(X)
{
    for (auto& e : vec)
        if (e.second == X)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Is that efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, you can use also [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```
std::string X{"foobar"};
return std::any_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                   [&X](const pair<short, string>& p)
                   { return p.second == X; });
```

Answer (score 11):

Your solution looks fine if you only want to know if there is an element satisfying your criteria present. I would use `const` references in the loop, because the loop should not change the elements of the vector:

```
for (const auto& e : vec) ....
```

If you want to use a standard library algorithm, you can try [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
const std::string X{"foobar"};

auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), 
                       vec.end(), 
                      [&X](const pair<short, string>& p)
                      { return p.second == X; });
```

Here, `it` is an iterator to the first element satisfying the condition, or equal to `vec.end()` if no element is found.

Comment: Does your solution use const reference?

Comment: @sehe:I meant the capture. I was just a little ironic.

Comment: @user2672165 It is `const` now :-) My understanding is that there is no mechanism to capture as "reference to `const` when the referee is not `const` in the context in which it is captured.

Comment: It is my understanding as well.

Comment: If you can make the data sorted on the `second` field, perhaps replace with binary searching: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/710af000893f3d4b

Comment: @juanchopanza It is my understanding that the reference is implicitly `const` - unless you would have marked the lambda as `mutable` :) But you _knew_ that, right o.O

Comment: @sehe No, that was not what I *knew*. I thought there was some non-intuitive wishy-washiness that meant that in fact the reference is taken as non-const. Either that is right or my gcc (4.8.1.) and clang (3.4) are broken (and I hope they are, and that I am wrong, becuause I would not want this to be the correct behaviour.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Wow. Now I'll have to check my understanding... :( Thanks for the heads up, will check things later.

Comment: @sehe By-reference captures are always non-const; it's the by-value captures that are `const` by default (because the lambda's `operator()` is `const` unless the lambda is declared `mutable`).

Comment: @Angew Ah. I'd almost say /WHY/, but I remembered: [tag:c++] :) (I understand why, in case you were going to explain :))

Answer (score 4):

In fact you can have your cake and eat it, if you are free to sort the `vector` of pairs based on the `second` field.

In this case you end up reinventing what Boost calls `flat_(multi_)map`. The obvious benefit is that searching can be done in O(log(n)) instead of linear time.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/710af000893f3d4b)**

```
using namespace std;

#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<short, std::string> Pair;

struct Cmp 
{
    bool operator()(Pair const& a, Pair const& b) const { return a.second < b.second; };
    bool operator()(Pair const& a, std::string const& b) const { return a.second < b; };
    bool operator()(std::string const& a, Pair const& b) const { return a < b.second; };
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Pair> vec = { 
        { 1, "aap" }, 
        { 2, "zus" }, 
        { 3, "broer" }
    };

    Cmp cmp;
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);

    auto it = std::binary_search(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::string("zus"), cmp);

    std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
2: zus
42: zus
```

Comment: +1, but I believe you mean `flat_(multi)map`, not `flat_(multi_)map` ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use an [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead, which will provide a preffy efficient [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) member function:

```
std::map<std::string, short>
// …
auto it = map.find(X);
```

This is as efficient as it goes for this kind of lookup (which is guaranteed to be `O(log(N))`).

Comment: +1 for the observation. The have-your-cake-and-eat-it approach is in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23174763/85371) now.